# Jenkins: pipelineJob with SCM and static script

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I would love to use Jenkins job-dsl `pipelineJob` for creating a build job for a GitHub repository with a static (and centrally maintained) pipeline.

But looking at the documentation (https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory.pipelineJob-definition) I can either create a `cps` with a static script or `cpsScm` with a SCM **and a reference to the `Jenkinsfile` in the repository**.

The requirement for having SCM defined comes from the `gitParameter` plugin, which I want to use for picking a git revision.

Is there a way how I can use a static script for the pipeline together with the SCM?

---

Update:
This is concretely what I would like to do:

- defining a pipeline job
- using a git Parameter to select the revision
- declare the particular script inline

```html
    pipelineJob("test") {
            parameters {
                gitParameter {
                    name('revision')
                    type('PT_BRANCH_TAG')
                    defaultValue('origin/master')
                    selectedValue('DEFAULT')
                    description('')
                    branch('')
                    branchFilter('')
                    tagFilter('')
                    useRepository('')
                    quickFilterEnabled(true)
                }
            }
            logRotator {
                numToKeep(50)
            }
    
            definition {
                cpsScm {
                    scm {
                        git {
                            remote {
                                github("<my-repo>")
                                credentials('github')
                            }
    
                            branch('$revision')
                        }
                    }
    
                    script("""
    @Library(value='pipeline-lib@master', changelog=false) _
    myPipeline projectName: 'test-name' 
    """)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: To answer your question literally: yes, you can paste the `Jenkinsfile` into the job console and then use the `checkout` class to retrieve the code. However, this may not be what you are actually asking. In that case, please provide an example of what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Hi Matt, I added some more details. Does that help?

Comment: Yes then my comment is relevant for what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I miss something here. Do you mean, that I should just create a pipeline with the above `pipelineJob` definition?
That won't work since, the `script` is only available for `cps` definitions and not for `cpsScm`. The latter, I must use for the parameter `gitParameter` to be able to retrieve available tags and branch names.

Do you know an alternative to `gitParameter`?

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline as code has incorporated many functions of jobs-dsl, which is probably why some of the fine tuning capabilities are missing from jobs-dsl's `pipelineJob`. The examples given on the the [Git Parameter plugin page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/#plugin-content-branch-type---basic-usage) are actually in the pipelines, which could be be the script portion of the `cps` portion of the jobs-dsl definition. The code quoted in the question could be converted to:

```
    pipelineJob("test") {
            logRotator {
                numToKeep(50)
            }
 
            definition {
                cps {
                    script('''
                         pipeline {
                             agent any
                             libraries {
                                 lib("pipeline-lib@master")
                             }
                             parameters {
                                 gitParameter name: 'revision',
                                              type: 'PT_BRANCH_TAG',
                                              defaultValue: 'origin/master',
                                              selectedValue: 'DEFAULT',
                                              description: '',
                                              branch: '',
                                              branchFilter: '',
                                              tagFilter: '',
                                              useRepository: '',
                                              quickFilterEnabled: true
                             }
                             stages {
                                 stage('Build') {
                                     steps {
                                         git branch: "${revision}",
                                             url: <myrepo>,
                                             credentialsId: 'github'
                                         // not familiar with what the next line does, assuming it's a pipeline step
                                         myPipeline projectName: 'test-name' 
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                    ''')
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

This is for a declarative pipeline. There is also an example of scripted pipeline on the git parameter plugin page.